# redirect user to specific page after he register its no working, the user is being redirected to the homepage

Tags: php, laravel

I have a home page that has a link "Create Post" to create a new post (`<a href="{!! route('post.create') !!}">Create Post</a>`).

When this link is clicked, if the user is authenticated he should be allowed to access this create post page.

But if the user is not authenticated the user should be redirected to the login/register page. After he login or register he should be redirected to the create post page. The login part is working the register part is not working.

I have the code below to do this but when the user dont have an account and click in "Create Post" he is redirected to the login page and in this login page there is a link to the register page. If the user click in this register link will be redirected to the register page. In this page he need to enter the name, email and password and submit the form, and because he previously cicked in the "Create Post" link he should be redirected to the create post page but its not working, he is being redirected to the homepage and not to the create post page.

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users ', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::post('/post/store', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@store',
        'as'   => 'post.store'
    ]);

    Route::get('/createPost', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@create',
        'as'   => 'post.create'
    ]);
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**Register Controller:**

```
 class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

        ]);
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/createPost');
    }

}
```

**Full Register Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request as AuthRequest;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

        ]);
    }

    protected function registered(AuthRequest $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect('/createPost');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After he login or register he should be redirected to the create post page. The login part is working the register part is not working

You can override the `register()` method in `RegisterController`:

```
protected function registered($request, $user)
{
    return redirect('some_page');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is appearing this error with that method: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::registered() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given. Do you know why?

Comment: @jon it means that you've added `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to the controller. If you don't use it, just change it to `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;`. You can also use full namespace or do this `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request as AuthRequest;` and `protected function registered(AuthRequest $request, $user)`

Comment: @jon are you talking about `RegisterController`? Also, if you're not comfortable with this, you could just do this `protected function registered($request, $user)`

Comment: Also with "use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request as AuthRequest; and protected function registered(AuthRequest $request, $user)" it appears: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::registered() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

Comment: Yes i will put in the question the full RegisterController.

Comment: @jon I'm sorry, I can't test it right now. Have you tried to remove type hinting as I've shown in the previous comment? I'm pretty sure this will work.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I dont know if its some issue with routes because when the user click in "Create Post" and then is redirected to the register page and register after he register is redirected to "proj.dev/createPost". But if a authenticated user click in "Create Post" he is redirected to "proj.dev/users%20/createPost".

Answer (score 0):

Override `$redirect` in `registerController`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

to

```
protected $redirectTo = '/create_post';
```

this is a static way.

Comment: Thanks, but the user should only be redirected to the create post page after register if he clicks in the create new post link and he is not authenticated. Changing the $redirectTo to create_post, the user is always redirected to create_pos after register.

Comment: yes. that's why i said that this is static way :-) . i'm also working on it to do so in my project. needed to share what i done so far